# Firestore: How to correctly update multiple docs with a query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

Base on this:
[Can Firestore update multiple documents matching a condition, using one query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947499/can-firestore-update-multiple-documents-matching-a-condition-using-one-query)

I do below but not very sure why I am getting this error: doc.update is not a function.

```
let db = firebase.firestore()
db.collection('posts')
  .where('uid', '==', userId)
  .get()
  .then((snapshots) => {
    snapshots.forEach((doc) =>
      doc.update({
        username: username,
      })
    )
  })
```

All the posts have a uid field and I am trying to change the username.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `doc` itself is not the reference to the document. It's a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) which has a property `ref` which is a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference). Try this:

```
let db = firebase.firestore()
db.collection('posts')
  .where('uid', '==', userId)
  .get()
  .then(async (snapshots) => {
    const updates = []
    snapshots.forEach((doc) =>
      updates.push(doc.ref.update({
        username: username,
      }))  
    )
    await Promise.all(updates)
  })
```

You can also use a [batch write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) instead of pushing separate update promises.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** See the answer provided by Dharmaraj for a more simple, straightforward answer. I didn't consider using the `.ref` property as he suggests, which makes a lot of sense.

Also, my answer assumed the `userID` was equal to the document ID, which actually wasn't the case in this scenario. Using a query is needed when the document ID and the userID are not equal.

---

The [`querySnapshot.forEach()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#foreach) function passes a ["QueryDocumentSnapshot"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot#constructors) to the callback, and this QueryDocumentSnapshot does not have the `update()` method available.

From the docs:
["A Query refers to a Query which you can read or listen to. You can also construct refined Query objects by adding filters and ordering."](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Query)
Notice the specification "read" and "listen". So if you want to write to a document, you will need to use something besides a query.

The `update()` method is available on [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference). (If you read the quick description on the DocumentReference you'll notice it does specify 'write' as a use-case) So if we rewrote your code above to get a DocumentReference rather than a query it would look something like this:

```js
let db = firebase.firestore();

// grabbing the DocumentReference that has a document id equal to userID
let userRef = db.collection('posts').doc(userID); 

// update that document
userRef.update({username: username})
```

Here I'm just getting the DocumentReference using the `.doc()` method and storing the value in `userRef`. Then I can update that document with `.update()`.

I hope this helped!

Comment: getting an error:  prebuilt-038c95ef-26ab9a06.js?e283:188 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Requested entity was not found.

Comment: @DarylWong It's possible the requested document does not exist in the collection. Regardless, I think Dharmaraj provided a more simple solution.

Comment: @DarylWong So I see now you probably got an error because the document ID and the userID are not equal. I missed the image provided in the question, so I didn't know they were not equal and assumed they were. If you use an auto document ID then you could not use `.doc(userID)` without getting an error.