# Firestore function to listen for updates

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am a beginner in React native and firestore, and using these to build a kind of social media app, and I have a weird problem(I think I structured the db the wrong way). I want to have a feed, with all posts, no following-based, no nothing. The first time I structured my posts in db like this: users(collection)->user(doc)->thisUserPosts(collection inside doc) - but I couldn't find a way to fetch through all the thisUserPosts from all user(doc) and display them properly.

So I re-structured the db like this:
2 main collection, posts and users. Completely different. In users collection, only docs of users and their data(name, age, etc). In the other, their posts(name, media, desc, AND userId - where userId == the person who created it. userId field from posts collection docs should exist in users collection).

This second approach works just fine. In feed, I only fetch posts. **But the problem arrises** when I try to open the post(need to have this feature). I need to be able to display on react-navigation header the name of the user, yet I only have details of the post and only userId, which is to no good use.

So I came up with a solution : add a userName field in the posts collection doc, next to userId and simply display that. Now here's the catch: I need to figure a way(in firestore I think) to listen to updates from users collection docs, in case a user updates his name/username(I don't want to showcase the old name). And I don't know if that's possible inside firestore or how. Or is it better to find a different db structure?

**TLDR: Need a function in firestore to listen to updates from other collection OR restructuring the db.**

Comment: If you are not using [Cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) then you should remove the `google-cloud-functions` tag :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are fetching posts of a single user then you can just set a listener for his document.
Make sure that document has no sensitive information that must not be shared with others and is limited to the owner only.

If you are fetching posts from multiple users then you can use `in` operator:

```
db.collection("users").where("userID", "in", ["user_id1", "user_id2"])
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.docs.map(user => user.data()))
    });
```

If I assume you will be updating the new name in all the user's posts then you can set the listener on the posts document itself but that won't be nice in case all 30 posts fetched are from same user. That'll end up costing 30 reads just to update the same name.

**Edit:**
A simple example of reading a user's posts and listening updates on the user name:

```
const userID = "my_user_id"

// fetching user's 30 posts
const postsRef = firebase.firebase().collection("posts").where("userID", "==", userID).limit(30)
const postsSnapshot = await postsRef.get()
const postsData = postsSnapshot.docs.map(post => post.data())
// Array of posts data objects

// listening to change in user's name
firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc("user_id")
    .onSnapshot((doc) => {
        console.log("data: ", doc.data());
        const newUsername = doc.data().username
        const updatedPostsData = postsData.map(post => {
          return ({...post, username: newUsername})
        })
    });
```

Comment: I am fetching all posts. All posts, from all users in a single collection called 'posts'. The only thing that differentiate them, is that I added a field userid that is automatically added when post is created. Userid. == firebase.auth().currentUser.uid . I only need to update those posts in that collection that require updating.

Comment: @flaneurx so if you are fetching posts from a single user then just set a listener on the user's document. It'll cost only 1 read to get updated name for each client. Then just loop through the array of documents that you've fetched and update the username in them.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that a bit If you don't mind? As I said I am a bit new to firestore

Comment: Also created a visual structure of the database, I thought it will help : https://imgur.com/a/AHLEufA

Comment: @flaneurx to keep it simple: 1. fetch user's posts. 2. Add a listener on user's document in users collection.

Comment: Thanks! Accepted it! Could it also be done as such: When user updates his profile, update both his profile, and search through posts with his uid and update those too? Or is your way a more scalable way?(that way, if a user has 100 posts, he performs 100+1 writes)

Comment: @flaneurx yes that's possible and I have an answer for that too :) Check it out here -> [How to correctly update multiple docs with a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68378313/13130697)