# Delete document by content of a field in Firestore (flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a subcollection 'favourites' under my 'users' collection and I would like to delete any of its documents by checking that the field 'prod_id' is isEqualTo `prodId`

THis is how I create the subcollection & document when a user taps the favourite button:

```
      _usersCollectionReference
          .doc(userId)
          .collection('favourites')
          .add({'prod_id': prodId});
```

Now, I want to be able to delete this document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do a check on the collection itself with where logic

```
const snapshot = await contentRef.where('favouritething','==', favoriteId)
  
  .get().then((querySnapshot)=>{
// return query snapshot 
      return querySnapshot.docs
      // .map(doc => doc.data());

  })
```

Answer (score 3):

To delete any document you must know it's ID or have a [`DocumentReference`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html) to it. For that you just need to know the `userId` and fetch documents where `prod_id` is equal to the product IDs you want to delete.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('users')
  .doc(userId)
  .collection('favourites')
  .where('prod_id', whereIn: [...])
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) {
    // ... 
  });
```

`snapshots` is a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) and has a property `docs` which is an array of [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot-class.html). You can loop through that array and delete each document by accessing their `reference`.

For example, deleting first document in that would be:

```
snapshot.docs[0].reference.delete()
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68378313/13130697) uses Javascript but should be good to clarify the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this very **easily** and **return** a **result**

```
    let contentArray: any[] = []
  // call the content collection
  const contentRef = db.collection('favourites');
  // snapshot data on get
  const snapshot = await contentRef.get().then((querySnapshot)=>{
// return query snapshot 
      return querySnapshot.docs
      // .map(doc => doc.data());

  })
  // this statement can be joined to the other
  // loop through each snapshot as document
 snapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
   // create new constant as document of each loop
    const newdoc = doc.data()
    // push new constant to content array
    if(newdoc.YOURTHING==='your thing you want to look for'){
    const deleteDocId=newdoc?.id

db.collection('favourites').doc(`${deleteDocId}`).delete().then((result)=>{
              return result
            })
   }

  })
})
```

You can **read** about **why** and **how** here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough. Passing the userId isn't sufficient to know which specific favourite document to delete. To know this, I need to check one of the fields of the favourite document which is where I store the productId and see that it is equal to the prodId received. In other words I (think) have to query the favourite collection/document for the value of a particular field and if that value is equal to the value I received from the onTap, I can then delete that document.

Comment: I understand what you want to do give me a second and I will update the answer above.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll try this out immediately and update you asap.

Comment: this won't be exact William no ones answer will be but it will be very close to what you want - the idea is to loop through each document on a collection and if it matched your variable either let var or const - then it will delete that item.  Just be careful if this is a very large collection it can be expensive.  you can further refine this by using ref and where on the collection query if you wanted too as well.

Comment: This is understood, Chris