# how to select a specific doc by a condition and update it flutter firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i want to update a document in a sub collection where i query it by a condition

//The method 'update' isn't defined for the type 'Query'

```
games.doc(invCode).collection('usersInGame').where('answer', isEqualTo : 'value')
```

my try is to get the doc

```
games.doc(invCode).collection('usersInGame').where('answer', isEqualTo : 'value')
  ..then((value) => value.docs.map((e) {
      games
          .doc(invCode)
          .collection('questions')
          .doc(e.id)
          .update({'answer': ''});
    }))
```

but it does not update in firestore any help ?

Comment: games.doc(invCode).collection('usersInGame').where('answer', isEqualTo : 'value')
my try is to get the doc 
games.doc(invCode).collection('usersInGame').where('answer', isEqualTo : 'value').get().then((value) => value.docs.map((e) {
              games
                  .doc(invCode)
                  .collection('questions')
                  .doc(e.id)
                  .update({'answer': ''});
            }))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first error is quite expected, as Firebase doesn't support update queries. See a.o. [Can Firestore update multiple documents matching a condition, using one query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947499/can-firestore-update-multiple-documents-matching-a-condition-using-one-query/48950404#48950404)

The second code snippet reads documents from `usersInGame` and then updates documents in the `questions` collection. If you want to update the documents matching your condition themselves, that'd be:

```
games.doc(invCode).collection('usersInGame')
  .where('answer', isEqualTo : 'value')
  ..then((value) => value.docs.forEach((doc) {
      doc.reference.update({'answer': ''});
    }))
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `get()` on the query.

Try this:

```
games
  .doc(invCode)
  .collection('usersInGame')
  .where('answer', isEqualTo: 'value')
  .get() // <-- You missed this
  .then((value) => value.docs.map((e) {
        games
          .doc(invCode)
          .collection('questions')
          .doc(e.id)
          .update({'answer': ''});
      }));
```