# flutter firebase: Update multiple docs at once

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My app allows users to make a `post`. From this post, any user can make a `request`.
I want to make a function where the owner of the post can update a field in all the requests made to his/her `post`, Let's say 'canceled' or 'delete' for example.

The picture below might help explain what I meant

[image: diagram for updating]

The user 'A' accesses his/her posts `Main collection`. Then there is a button that says **CANCEL**.
On the click of this button `firebase` should check if there is a request sent to this post in the `Sub-collection`. If there is a request, then a field, say **'Post-Status'**, in all the requests made to this post should be updated.

I know this code is wrong but this is the best I could come up with.

```
// inside the TextButton

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('main-collection name').doc(current-user-id).collection('sub-collection name').doc("I don't know what to put here").set({"Post-Status": "Canceled"}).
```

**N/B:** when I tried the code below, without putting anyting in the doc() for the subcollection, it creates a whole new collection in the sub-collection

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('main-collection name').doc(current-user-id).collection('sub-collection name').doc().set({"Post-Status": "Canceled"}).
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947499/can-firestore-update-multiple-documents-matching-a-condition-using-one-query